# matplotlib legend at the bottom of the plot

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

Im trying to replicate a chart the was done in AmCharts but so far Im confused in the way to make the legend be outside and at the bottom of the plot

right now im using this django view to render the plot

```
def my_view(request)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas

    colors = ["#FF9800", "#00E676", "#03A9F4", "#1A237E", "#AD1457", "#F44336", "#1DE9B6", "#01579B", "#CFD8DC",
          "#90A4AE", "#263238", "#B71C1C", "#FFEB3B"]

    data=('serv1','Aplicaiones','serv3','serv4','servi5','serv1','serv2','serv3','serv4','servi5',)
    datos=[99.3,99,23,100,99.3,99,23,100,99.3,99]
    figure=plt.Figure()

    pos=np.arange(len(datos))
    ax = figure.add_subplot(111)

    b=ax.bar(pos, datos,color=colors)

    ax.legend(b,data,loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0,-.05, 1,0), ncol=5,mode="expand")


    ax.axis('off') #
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')

    figure.bbox_inches='tight'
    canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)

    canvas.print_png(response)

    return response
```

the parameter bbox_to_anchor looks like the way to go, but chart has a limit and the label ends too close to the bars, my goal is to put the label (1 for each bar) leave space for axis description

what I want https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/2U113d3m0O3Z0o053L3F/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202017-10-23%20a%20la(s)%2023.45.00.png?v=16e23ee7

right now this is what I got https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/0l0v2P2N3h1M15022V43/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202017-10-23%20a%20la(s)%2023.47.05.png?v=a36b97c9

Comment: Have you looked at this answer by Joe Kington? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/4701285?s=1|203.5537#4701285
 Last example has the legend separately at the bottom. I think what you also need to do is shrink your plot a bit with ax.set_position().

Comment: looks like my searching skils had faded with the time. thanks for pointing out the solution.